# How can i give the selected attribute to a item in an array fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, sql

I have a select dropdown that i wish to have a predefined selected option based on SQL data.

My sql call:

```
$sel = 'SELECT threechar_currency_code, currency_name FROM currencies';
$RS = doQuery($sel);
while($row = fetchAssoc($RS)){

   //The else is working, the code in the if() is what i wish to get working
/* if ($row['threechar_currency_code'] === $selected_currency){
    $currencies[] = array(
        'selected' => true,
        'currency_code' => $row['threechar_currency_code'],
        'currency_name' => $row['currency_name']
    );
}  else { */
    $currencies[] = array(
        'currency_code' => $row['threechar_currency_code'],
        'currency_name' => $row['currency_name']
    );
// }
}
```

My select:

```
<select class="mdb-select md-form" id="currency" name="currency" placeholder="Select currency" value=""
                                            required searchable="Search here..">
                                            <option value="none" disabled selected="selected">Currency</option>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($currencies as $c){
                                                echo '<option value="'.$c['currency_code'].'">'.$c['currency_name'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
```

To specify, everything populates fine with just the else{} i just wish to have a preselected option if it matches the preselected value. Thanks in advance

Comment: So - check if the value matches the pre-selected one, and if so, output the `selected` attribute? Where is the actual _problem_?

Comment: If there is no match here $row['threechar_currency_code'] === $selected_currency and you are expecting one, print out the values to see whats happening.

Comment: I wish to have the select to allready be selected on one of the options, which i have gotten from another query to the database @CBroe

Comment: I allready know there is a match and i get into the if statement as i have printed the values, in addition i have also tried this with hardcoded values aswell and it still doesnt preselect the option @Grumpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you hard-coded the default option. Remove it and do the staff in `foreach` loop (use your `if` in the loop).

Comment: Moving the if to the foreach and setting selected there worked out, thank you so much for the assistance!

Comment: This isn't a very future-proof solution, you need to build the data in the way it's going to be used.  If/when OP graduates to MVC (or any other pattern where the data isn't all in the same file) the code will potentially break again as `$selected_currency` may no longer be present in the scope

Comment: Do you believe the answer you provided bellow is a more future proof solution even though the $selected_currency i wrote was mostly just metacode and the variable is actually a sessionvariable? If you still believe that is a safer solution i will change the accepted answer and rewrite the code @jameson2012

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `selected` attribute in your loop if it exists

```
echo '<option value="'.$c['currency_code'].'" ' . (isset($c['selected']) ? "selected=true" : "") . '> . $c['currency_name']</option>
```

I'd also simplify your `while` loop.  You need the two main attributes every time so alwasy create them and only add the selected if you need it e.g.

```
while($row = fetchAssoc($RS)){

   $currency = [
     'currency_code' => $row['threechar_currency_code'],
     'currency_name' => $row['currency_name']
   ]
   if($row['threechar_currency_code'] === $selected_currency) {
     $currency['selected'] = true;
   }
   $currencies[] = $currency;     
}
```